# hovering background with opacity value and hovering button with opacity different value

Tags: html, css, asp.net

Am facing Simple problem while applying hover ,
my point is I want to hover the box , the opacity of the box should be 0.3 , and the button inside the box should be with opacity (1).
so I tried to apply this task but no luck.

when hover the the box , the box should have opacity with 0.3 , and the button inside the box should have opacity (1).

```css
body {
  margin: .5em;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #E8E8E8;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: .9em;
  direction: rtl;
}

#cell_1 {
  margin: 0 -3px 1em 0;
  padding: 8px;
  float: right;
  width: 61%;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #9BBB59;
  height: 100px;
}

.middle {
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

#cell_1:hover {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

#cell_1:hover .middle {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <!--//end #postHeader//-->
  <div id="centerColumn">
    <!--//end #navbar//-->
    <div id="header" style="text-align:right">
      <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/APP_EOM/EO/Hed2.png" Width="100%" />
    </div>
    <!--//end #headern//-->
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
    <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
    <h2> heading 2:</h2>
    <p style="font-size:15px; line-height:1.5em; font-weight:normal">
      testiest test teset teset
    </p>
    <!-- Start Cell_1 -->
    <div id="cell_1" dir="rtl">
      <h2>????? ???????</h2>
      <p style="font-size:14px;  font-weight:normal"> ABCDEFG .</p>
      <p> </p>
      <div class="middle">
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="text" Text="teeeest" style="background-color: #297c1c;border:none;color:white;padding:7px 32px;text-align:right;text-decoration:none;cursor:pointer;" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--//end #cell_1//-->
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give Background `rgba` to `:before` of *#cell_1*

```css
#cell_1 {
 margin: 0 -3px 1em 0;
 padding: 8px;
 float: right;
 width: 61%;
 height: 100px;
 border-radius: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
 position: relative;
 height: 100px;
}
#cell_1:before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #9BBB59;
 z-index: -1;
}
.middle {
 transition: .5s ease;
 opacity: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 text-align: center;
}
#cell_1:hover:before {
 background-color: rgba(155, 187, 89, .3);
}
#cell_1:hover .middle {
 opacity: 1;
}
.my-btn {
 background-color: green;
 color: white;
 font-size: 16px;
 padding: 16px 32px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!-- Start Cell_1 -->
<div id="cell_1" dir="rtl">
  <h2>????? ???????</h2>
  <p style="font-size:14px;  font-weight:normal"> ABCDEFG  .</p>
  <div class="middle">
    <button class="my-btn">Test</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!--//end #cell_1//-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using opacity you can just use

```
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi i worked on your issue..as per your code when u give opacity for parent which is lesser thn its child on that time it won't work ....so debug once below code its working now...[pls check the below link](http://jsfiddle.net/emq2vfhx/)

```
enter code here
```